# Give wp link pages it's own template

Tags: templates, paginate-links, nextpage

Here's the scenario, I'm working on a site with 100s of of paged posts using the wp_link_pages tag.

The issue I'm having is that they're things I want displayed on the main post that I don't want display of the paged parts of the post and vice versa.

How can I achieve that? And is it possible to give the paged parts of a post their own template?

Comment: so you want to display your "things" on the first page of all the posts? not on 2nd/third pages?

Comment: @Towfiq Yeah, they're things in the single.php template that I only want to show up on the main page of the post and not on the 2nd, 3rd, 4th etc. Which is why I was wondering if it's possible to the the 2nd, 3rd pages their own template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your single.php add this example code inside the loop:

```
<?php 
    global $page;
    if ($page == 1) {?>
    <div style="color:red;">This text should only appear on first page of the post!!!</div>
<?php } ?>
```

you can change the div with your thing that you wanted to display only on the first post page..

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no fork in [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) to template paginated posts differently (there is one for paginated archives).

If you at [`wp_link_pages()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_link_pages/) source it uses number of global variables to distinguish state of paginated post:

```
global $page, $numpages, $multipage, $more;
```

You would need to work with these directly to conditionally adjust content or markup.